# Bash Quoting Subshell Command Option With Equal Sign

Tags: bash

Why is this

```
function wtf()
{
  args="$*"
  set -o xtrace
  $(some_prog --option="$args") # note the '='
  set +o xtrace
}
$ wtf asd asd asd asd 
++ some_prog '--option=asd asd asd asd'
```

not the same as

```
function wtf2()
{
  args="$*"
  set -o xtrace
  $(some_prog --option "$args") # note no '='
  set +o xtrace
}
$ wtf2 asd asd asd asd
++ some_prog --option 'asd asd asd asd'
```

I believe I am running afoul of item #4 of [Simple Command Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Simple-Command-Expansion), but I'm not sure...

For reference, I want the behavior of the latter, to have `$args` be single-quoted. But I want to be able to use the equals sign, and I don't understand why the initial `'` quote from `$args` is being propagated to the whole of `--option=`.

Comment: `'--option=asd asd asd asd'` is the same as `--option='asd asd asd asd'`

Comment: It is in fact not because `some_prog` sees either `'--option=asd asd asd asd'` as the first positional argument in the first case and `'asd asd asd asd'` as the value of the keyword argument `--option` in the second case.

Comment: @JacobFaib It's different to the shell, but `some_prog` treats them the same. The `=` form of the option is useful when (for whatever reason) you can't provide two arguments `--option` and `asd asd asd asd` as easily as one argument `--option=asd asd asd asd`.

Comment: `'--option=asd asd asd asd'` is *not* a positional argument as far as `some_prog` is concerned.. The leading `--` is sufficient to flag it as an option with a "contained" argument, rather than an option that will be followed by an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of the `-x` will quote an entire word should any character in that word need to be escaped. That's why you see

```
'--option=asd asd asd asd'
```

instead of

```
--option='asd asd asd asd'
```

in the first case.

In the second case, the option and its argument are provided as two distinct words. Since nothing in `--option` requires quoting, it is not quoted.

The result is the same as far as `some_prog` is concerned. It will either use the word following `--option`, or the string following the `=` in `--option=...`, as the argument to the option named `option`.

(In neither case does `some_prog` actually seen any of the quotes; it only sees the two strings `--option` and `asd asd asd asd` or the single string `--option=asd asd asd asd`. It will split the latter on the `=` itself when needed.)

Comment: Right I see. So it was an apparent false positive cause by using `xtrace`. Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't call it a false positive, as nothing was being tested. The surrounding quotes you see in the trace output are *added* by the shell for display purposes only; they were never part of the string resulting from the quote removal applied by the shell during parsing/evaluation.